# AppEngine Backup from one app to another

Tags: backup, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I can't seem to restore my AppEngine backups to a new app as listed in the documentation.

We are using the cron backup as listed in the documentation.

I get through all the stages to launch the restore job successfully, but when it kicks of all the shards are failing with 503 errors.
I tried this with multiple backup files and the experience is the same.
any advice?

(Java runtime)﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this hoping this will help someone, as there is really lack of resources around Google's documentation and the web in general about this.

While the appengine documentation says this can be done, I actually found the piece of code that forbids this inside the data_storeadmin app.

I managed to connect through python remote-api shell, read an entity from the backup and tried saving to the datastore, but datastore.Put(entity) operation yielded: "BadRequestError: app s~app_a cannot access app s~app_b's data" so it seems to be on an even lower level.

In the end, I decided to restore only a specific namespace to the same app which was also a tedious task - but it did save the day.

I Managed to pull my backup locally through gsutil, install a python-remote-api version on my app, accessed the interactive shell and wrote this script:
https://gist.github.com/Shuky/ed8728f8eb6187475b9a

Hope this helps.
Shuky